# Lightweight gnome-keyring alternative

Tags: gnome, gnome-keyring, crunchbang

I'm thinking of ditching the Gnome desktop for something more lightweight (might even go Crunchbang instead). I do however like the gnome-keyring. It can be integrated to other software (i.e. offlineimap). I know that the gnome keyring are being deprecated for libsecret but I do believe that it is also tied to the Gnome desktop?

Are there any lightweight "key ring" alternative that would work with for example Crunchbag?

Comment: have you found an answer?